# Problem with extends database class with the web services class

Tags: java

I would like to create a class for every web service, the problem is when I extend the database class I can not use the methods of the class

Here my web services class which I do the query

```
public class getCustomer extends Database{

String sql="select....;";

Database db = new Database();//apro connessione al database

Connection _conn = ConDatabase();

PreparedStatement stmt =_conn.prepareStatement(sql);

@Override
public void disconnetti() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.disconnetti();
}
```

I can not import the connection and the method disconnect

disconnect method of Database class

```
public void disconnetti()
{
    try
    {
        stmt.close();
        _conn.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("errore: "+ e);
    }
}
```

I do not even know if the methodology is right

```
PreparedStatement stmt =_conn.prepareStatement(sql);
```

this instruction gives me an error

Comment: A database field inside something extending database doesn't seem right. Then again, it doesn't seem right that `getCustomer extends Database`, because a "getCustomer" *isn't a* `Database`.

Comment: Ok, but 
how do I pass the connection and the methods?

Comment: so: you both use inheritance AND composition for Database?

Comment: Unless you're doing this just to learn (in which case don't `catch Exception`, and use something more informative like `printStackTrace()`), it's usually better to use established libraries like JPA (Hibernate) and Spring Data instead of writing all of this code when tools to do it already exist.